# How do I debug this flickering URL Router.go issue in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I wish I can give a more detailed response, but I can't even figure out how to debug this situation.

**The situation:** When I click on the button, the URL changes for a split second to http://localhost:3000/register. Nothing new gets rendered, the page stays the same as if I didn't click anything. Things I've tried:

- Typing in `Router.go('/register')` in the console works properly
- I have tried this with every single route, not just the `/register` route
- I have tried this in both Firefox and Chrome
- This is not an issue if I use `{{pathFor 'templateName'}}` in the template, only when I use `Router.go('path')`

I have a link in my header to register:

```
Template.header.events({
  'click .register-btn': function(e) {
        Router.go('/register');
    }
});
```

And, of course, I have this in my template:
`<a href="#" class="register-btn">Contact</a>`

Here is my entire routing file, `router.js`:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

// Routes
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'landingPage',    // Main domain routing
    layoutTemplate: 'landingLayout',
    onBeforeAction: function (pause) {
            if (Meteor.user()) {
                Router.go('/home');
            } else {
                this.next();
            }
        }
});
Router.route('/home', {
    name: 'siteHome',
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        if (this.ready()){
            if (!Meteor.loggingIn())
                AccountsTemplates.ensureSignedIn.call(this);
        }else{
            // render the loading template but keep the url in the browser the same
            this.render('loading');
            this.renderRegions();
        }
    }
});

Router.route('/weekly_goal/set', {
    name: 'setWeeklyGoal'
});
Router.route('/make_entry', {
    name: 'makeEntry'
});

// Login and Register Routes
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login',
    template: 'siteLogin',
});
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
    name: 'register',
    path: '/register',
    template: 'siteRegister',
    redirect: '/',
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor Page Refreshing with Button Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005070/meteor-page-refreshing-with-button-click)

Comment: That's it! Adding `e.preventDefault()` fixed it. Feel free to type out the full answer and I'll give you the green check mark. Can't believe I missed this! Thank you so much.

Comment: Done! No problem - it's one of those things that *everyone* get's confused by the first time they hit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a button inside of a form, the default browser behavior is to submit the form which causes another HTTP request and reloads the page. In order to avoid this, your event handler needs to explicitly prevent the default behavior:

```
Template.header.events({
  'click .register-btn': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Router.go('/register');
  }
});
```